# Iteration with limit (eigenvalues/convergence)

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Let $A$ be a matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$ and associated eigenvectors $p_+$ and $p_-$. Let $\eta >0$.

It's $x_0=\alpha_+p_++\alpha_-p_-$ for $\alpha_+,\alpha_- \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_{k+1}=\alpha_+(1-\eta \lambda_+)^{k+1}p_++\alpha_-(1-\eta \lambda_-)^{k+1}p_-$

My question is:

Why $x_0 \in \mathrm{span} \lbrace p_+ \rbrace $ implies that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_k=\textbf{0}$ for $\eta >0$ chosen sufficiently small such that $|1-\eta \lambda_+|<1$ is satisfied?

My idea was:

Since $x_0 \in \mathrm{span} \lbrace p_+ \rbrace $ it follows that $\alpha_-=0$.

So $x_0=\alpha_+p_+ \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_k \in \mathrm{span} \lbrace p_+ \rbrace $

Now I don't know how to continue. Is this step true or how can it be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said $\alpha_-=0$, so:
$$x_{k}=\alpha_+(1-\eta \lambda_+)^{k}p_+$$
Since:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} ||x_{k}||=\lim_{k\to \infty} ||\alpha_+(1-\eta \lambda_+)^{k}p_+||$$
We have by the properties of norm:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} ||x_{k}||=\lim_{k\to \infty} |\alpha_+||1-\eta \lambda_+|^{k}||p_+||$$
Then:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} ||x_{k}||=|\alpha_+| ||p_+|| \lim_{k\to \infty} |1-\eta \lambda_+|^{k}$$
So if $ |1-\eta \lambda_+|<1$, we have:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} ||x_{k}||=0$$
Which by definition of limit in a normed vector space is equivalent to:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{k}=0$$

Comment: Still got one question: Can these steps also be done analogous with $x_{k+1}=\alpha_+(1-\eta \lambda_+)^{k+1}p_+$ in the same way or does it have to be shown with the iteration before $(x_k)$?

Comment: totally analogous

Comment: Then $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{k+1}=0$ implies that $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{k}=0$?

Comment: They are totally equivalent